# Paypal payment buttons - how do I test paying without paypal account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a website which has a Paypal payment button. When this button is pressed it takes the user to paypal to conduct the payment and gives the user a choice of either logging into their paypal account or just entering their credit card details.

I'm trying to test the latter option but I'm not sure what credit card details I need to provide in the Sandbox to allow me to submit a valid Credit card with valid expiry date and CVC code

Answer (score 0):

Use a credit card generator site to generate a test number.  I like [this site](http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/).  Any expiration date and security code will work as long as it's not passed the date, of course.